# how to take values from two lists and place a comma between them?

Tags: java, jsp, managed-bean

Example:

```
list1 : apple,mango,grapes

list2: orange,gauva,cherry
```

I want the out to be :

> apple,orange
>
> mango,gauva
>
> grapes,cherry.

And should be able to display the above output in the form of link on jsp.Please help me out for this .

Comment: I don't know what JSP is, but the comma thingy should be easy. Iterate through both lists simultaneously and take one element from either and add a comma between them. If they're unequal in size, handle that the way you wish (you did not specify)

Comment: are both list the same size???

Answer (score 0):

there are many approaches to do this:

here is one:

## If both list are the same size:

```
final List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
l1.add("mango");
l1.add("apple");
l1.add("grappes");

l2.add("orange");
l2.add("guava");
l2.add("cherry");

for (int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(l1.get(i) + "," + l2.get(i));
}
```

this will print:

> mango,orange
>
> apple,guava
>
> grappes,cherry